# Identifying which polygons lie within grid of polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, intersect

I work in ArcMap 10.8.1. I have a polygon layer of municipalities and a polygon layer of 1x1 km square zones of air polluted areas (it's not a raster). I need to find which of the municipalities are "hit" by the air pollution polygons. Situation is displayed in the picture.

Is there a tool in Toolbox to resolve this?

[image]

I managed to run Select by Location tool but the result is not satisfactory.

Why didn't the tool select every polygon that contained "the polluted polygons"?

As in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Select by Location?

Comment: What would I "Select by Location"? The municipalities polygons don't contain the air pollution data, that would be no problem. I need a mean to identify which polygons are hit by the red ones.

Comment: Open the tool and you will understand... Then add a field to your municipalities table and field calculate as "polluted" or whatever you want. Then the selected will get that attribute

Comment: Yes, that actually worked. I've mistaken it with Select by Attributes. Problem is solved!

Comment: I ran the Select By Location tool but it only selected some of the polygons containing the polluted polygons. Why didn't it select all of them? See the red squares in the picture.

Comment: When you ran the Select By Location tool what was your selection relationship?

Comment: It was "Contain the source layer feature"

Comment: Try intersect instead.

Comment: Yes, Intersect did work although it doesn't make sense, logically. Contain should work by the description (note that I didn't choose "contain completely"). So it's resolved. Thank you.